# Add a checkmark to the collection view's cell on tap

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've been trying to add a checkmark on the collection view's cell when it is tapped by the user, and if it's tapped again - remove it.

So far, I've written a code that adds the checkmark, but still I can't find a way to remove it.

My code:

```
 - (void)profilePicked:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture {

UIView *pickedView = (UIView* )[gesture view];
UIImageView *tick = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ticker"]];
tick.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 110);
tick.tag = 105;
tick.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

if(![pickedView.subviews containsObject:tick]) {
    [pickedView addSubview:tick];
} else {
    for (UIView *subview in pickedView.subviews) {
        if (subview.tag == 105) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }        [self.profilesCollection reloadData];
}

}
```

and :

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"profileCell";
InviterCollectionViewCell *cell = (InviterCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// some stuff happening here

UIView *circle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 110)];
//cell.profilePicture.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 110);
//cell.profilePicture.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[circle addSubview:imageView];

// Round the edges of the profile picture
circle.layer.cornerRadius = 55;
circle.clipsToBounds = YES;
[cell.contentView addSubview:circle];

cell.ticker.hidden = YES;

//Add Gesture Recognizer for the profile Picture
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(profilePicked:)];
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[circle addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
circle.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

return cell;

 }
```

I tried to implement some functionality in didSelectItemAtIndexPath and didDeselectItemAtIndexPath, but it didn't work as it should.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably want the code that display/adds the checkmark to the cell inside cellForRowAtIndexPath:, that way if the collectionView ever gets reloaded, your checkmark will still be on the right cells. Make the tick related to your model somehow as well

Comment: I created an array which for indexPath.row stores a 1 or 0 indicating whether the checkmark should be shown or not, but still it is not working.

Comment: @Alex Here's my didSelectItemAtIndexPath: ' - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    if ([self.selectedCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]) {
        //[self.invitedArray addObject:pickedProfile];
        [self.selectedCells replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        NSLog(@"Exec 1");
        [self.profilesCollection reloadData];
        
    }

        
    }
    
} '

Comment: Try to create simple UIImageView with checkmark image and set it hidden as initial and then when user select the cell change the UIImageView from hidden to visible state and vise vers ça

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution : 
**1** Add UIImageView, with checkmark Image, to your cell in storyboard or nib file then create the outlet for this imageView and set it to hidden mode 
**2** In your didSelectItemIndexPath method add this code :

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCollectionViewCell *cell = (MyCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     //check if the the checkmark image is hidden then change it to visible
    if(cell.checkMarkImage.hidden) 
       cell.checkMarkImage.hidden = NO;
    else
       cell.checkMarkImage.hidden = YES;

    [cell setSelected:YES];
}
```